# Flutter: pass quantity from main screen to other

Tags: flutter, dart

First, now i have succesfull add to cart, but i want to the detail(cartquantity) send to the next screen.but i cannot and i  dont know where is wrong.

For example, I in the second screen the cartquantity is null(but in main screen i have '1' number in there).

So,how can i do?

need add  refreshindicator??

```
//this is second screen that i want show the number.

class Detail extends StatefulWidget {
 final String code,cartquantity;
 final User user;
const Detail({Key key, this.user, this.code,this.cartquantity}) : super(key: key);
 @override
 _DetailState createState() => _DetailState();
}

class _DetailState extends State<Detail> {

Product product;
double screenHeight, screenWidth;
String cartquantity = "0";
 int quantity = 1;

//this is the place i want show the number.
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () async {
             if (widget.user.email == "unregistered@easy.com") {
              Toast.show("Please register to use this function", context,
                 duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
               return;
            } else if (widget.user.email == "admin@easy.com") {
               Toast.show("Admin mode!!!", context,
                   duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
              return;
           } else if (widget.user.quantity == "0") {
               Toast.show("Cart empty", context,
                 duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
             return;
            } else {
               await Navigator.push(
                 context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                     builder: (BuildContext context) => MainScreen(
                           user: widget.user,
                           )));
               
             _loadCartQuantity();

          }


           },

          icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
          label: Text(cartquantity=cartquantity,
        //style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black)
              ),
          backgroundColor:Color.fromRGBO(101, 255, 218, 50),

    ) );

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
 final String code;
 Final String cartquantity;
 final User user;
```

And down there:

```
   label: Text(cartquantity=widget.cartquantity),
```

Comment: ok it is works , but it may cannot show out the number that i  just added. And it with show the number that from main screen only and cannot update.In this case what should ido?

Comment: Share the rest of code an we can work on it

Comment: Thank yours tips 'state managment', i have already show the answers that i wants

Comment: Great! Keep on it, it's a very powerful concept that you will love working with.